# Why does Php multi curl return error pages on valid urls

Tags: php, curl, webrequest

I have quite a large number (around 50.000) of urls I want to fetch data from. In order to make execution faster I decided to use multi_curl in PHP. One multi_curl contains 30 urls, because I noticed, that whenever I add more urls to the multi_curl, some HTML elements are lost. After using the package of 30 urls I noticed another problem. When fetching the HTML from the curls a few urls return just a 404 error page which shouldn't be the case as they are valid urls. These urls do work when making a single curl-request for each of them. Is this a known problem of multi_curl and is there any fix?

Setting up urls and adding them to array:

```
foreach ($urls as $id => $url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
        
            // Set all your options for each connection here
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
    
            $curls[$url] = $ch;
            curl_multi_add_handle($cmh,$ch);
            $urlCtr++;
        }
```

Executing multi_curl-handles:

```
do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($cmh, $active);
        }
        while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    
        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
            if (curl_multi_select($cmh) != -1) {
                do {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($cmh, $active);
                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }
        }
```

Fetching HTML-data from curls:

```
foreach ($curls as $url=>$ch) {
            if($updateCtr == 7)
            {
                $f = 0;
            }
            $response = curl_multi_getcontent($ch); // get the content
                    // do what you want with the HTML
            
            file_put_contents("sqlCommands.txt",$response);
            $html = new simple_html_dom($response);
            $list = $html->find('table[class="ta"]', 0);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($cmh, $ch);}
```

I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Either the URLs are wrong, or you're hitting a rate limit and the server is returning a 404 error in response.

Comment: The urls are definitely working so it probably is a rate limit problem. Any ideas on how to avoid this while still having the best possible performance? At the moment I just check wheter the response contains the 404 error or not. If it contains the error I make a seperate single curl-request, but this still takes quite a long time since about every second or third response of the multi_curl returns 404.

Comment: What I've done in one application was to keep retrying the request in a loop, with increasing time between retries, up to some limit.

Comment: Okay, yeah as already mentioned I implemented a similar solution. Can't think of a way to speed it up a little bit more at the moment. Nevertheless, thank you for your help!